# Round float in C in STM32F

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, stm32

I'd like to round two float values two only two decimals.

This is the array of floats:

```
float result[2];
```

This is the rounding operation:

```
result[0] = roundf( result[0] * 100 ) / 100;
result[1] = roundf( result[1] * 100 ) / 100;
```

For the value of :

> -3.99520659

I expect -4, and I get -4

But For the value of :

> 8.07999992

I expect 8, but I get the same number.

For other ocasions I'd like the numbers to look like 3.4 o -2.1

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "I get the same number" you mean "-4" ? Post the code please.

Comment: Why do you expect 8, not 8.08?

Comment: What STM32 chip are you working on? Some of them has floating point hardware (any chip with a Cortex M4F or M7 core), others don't. So I don't even know if the issue is with fp hardware or soft float library implementation. Which one it is will dictate the debugging process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably correctly rounding 8.07999992 to 8.08.  But then it's probably getting printed out as 8.07999992 again.  This is due to the limited precision of floating point (and the even more limited precision of type `float` as opposed to `double`), and the fact that, in binary, there is no such number as 8.08.

Try these two things:

1. Print your result using `%.2f`, and again using `%.20f`.  (I assume you're using `printf`.)
2. Use type `double` instead of `float`.

The other question to ask is, why are you trying to round these numbers?  Is it because they're only significant to two places?  Is it because you want to display them that way?  Is it because they're supposed to represent dollars and cents (or some other centidecimal currency)?

- If the quantities are only significant to two places, rounding as you're currently doing should be correct.
- If you want to display a floating-point number to two places, just use `%.2f`, and don't worry about explicitly rounding it yourself.
- If you're trying to manipulate dollars and cents, it's often much easier to use integer math (representing cents) across the board.

Comment: Yes, I verified that `8.08` in `float` can be `8.07999992...` via [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Comment: It is not about "limited precision" - a float has precision of _approximately_ 6 significant _decimal_ digits.  The problem is that the representation is _binary_ floating point, which does not coincide with decimal _presentation_.  Other than the term "limited precision" however, this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

A binary floating point is used for `float` that does not exactly coincide with *decimal* presentation.  When you use `roundf()` you are rounding the *binary* representation. When that is *presented* in decimal, the mismatch between the internal representation and the presentation is clear.

The solution is not to round the floating point variable at all, but to specify the *presentation* with a format specifier in `printf( "%.2f", f )` for example.

You will fine for example 8.084 will round to 8.07999992 because that is the nearest binary floating point value to 8.08.

Note that `float` good for approximately 6 significant decimal digits, is all you can rely 8.07999 on the trailing ...992 should normally be ignored.